# VB.NET Forms shift over on certain PCs

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a .NET application that is in the testing phase right now, and on a couple user's screens the area of certain forms gets shifted over to the left:

[image]

For reference, here is how it appears on my machine:
[image]

I don't have any code currently in place to resize the form dynamically, and it's not an issue of the forms not fitting on the screen, they just get wacked out. I've been researching this one for weeks and can't seem to find a solution.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you set your controls' `Anchor` and `Dock` properties to?

Comment: Does it act this on all pc's except yours or just a few? if just a few I would start with the display settings on those pc's to see if they have changed something like maybe the font size to 150%.

Comment: Check the DPI settings of the affected machines.